# how to empty reference object in angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

I am trying to empty my reference object .But it is not deleting or removing my chart . I make two directive and communicate  with shared service.But then I delete my reference object .it not deleted my chart ..on click of **"delete" button** i need to delete my chart ..
is it possible ?because I take reference objects

here is my code

http://plnkr.co/edit/TzUlqoh4sYVjH3ADRTGL?p=preview

```
angular.module('app',['header','chartm','hig']).controller('cntrl',function(){

}).service('sharedService',function(){
  var vm =this;
  vm.chartData={};
  vm.displatChart=displatChart;
  vm.deleteChart=deleteChart;

  function deleteChart(){
    vm.chartData={};
  }

    function displatChart() {
            var orderData = {
                chart: {
                    type: 'bar'
                },
                title: {
                    text:'Order Execution Status '
                },
                colors: ['#2f7ed8','#910000','#8bbc21','#1aadce'],

                xAxis: {
                    categories: [1,2,4]
                },
                yAxis: {
                    min: 0,
                    title: {
                        text: ''
                    }
                },
                legend: {
                    reversed: true
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    series: {
                        stacking: 'normal'
                    }
                },
                series: [ {

                    name: 'Excecuted',
                    data: [1,2,3]
                },{
                    name: 'Placed',
                    data: [4,3,2]
                }]
            };
            vm.chartData=orderData;
            return vm.chartData;
        }

})
```

**Update**

If I do wrong in architecture please provide me good way to do this task ?

I try another way i am able to delete but not generate again

http://plnkr.co/edit/TzUlqoh4sYVjH3ADRTGL?p=preview

```
  vm.delete=function(){
    alert('delete');
    sharedService.deleteChart();
    $('#myChart').html('')
  }

  vm.add=function(){
    alert('add');
    sharedService.displatChart();
  }
```

any update ?

Comment: The architecture of your angular app isn't quite what it should be, which is what is causing the problems..

Comment: please suggest the best way to do this or architecture

Comment: when you click on delete , it must call the appropirate function in the service who will delete the object, and return the new object so the function who call the `deleteChart()` can get and store in the new content

Comment: Shouldn't the functions be in the controller, rather than in the service? You could try $scope.$apply to force a digest cycle and make Angular aware of changes

Comment: what is best way to do this ...? to do this task

Comment: `function deleteChart(){ vm.chartData={}; return vm.chartData;  }`

Comment: @JeremyThille if I used in controller the I will communicate directives

Comment: any better way to do this ?

Comment: "the I will communicate directives" ?

Comment: sorry .If I will not take shared service then how I will communicate between two directives

Comment: please check update ...

Comment: You need to change the `service` to a `factory`, have a separate controller for each view and directive. Then use the `factory` for intercommunication

Comment: I already make different controllers ..Please check plunker..I make only service ..what will be the change if I use factory