# How can I delete a property from an object in Angular using diectives?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I  make a two directive's .On one directive I have **delete** button.and second directive I get a object value form shared service .Now I want to delete that value from delete button ,I try to empty my object but it is not taking place why ..? if i am doing wrong what is best way to do this task ?

plunker
http://plnkr.co/edit/Yenmira9J9XpjscQzRoX?p=preview

code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="app">
    <a></a>
    <b></b>
    <script>
      angular.module('app',[]).directive('a',function(){

     return {
    restrict :'E',
    scope:{},
    templateUrl:'a.html',
    controller:'ts',
    controllerAs:'vm'
  }

      }).controller('ts',function(sharedService){
        var vm=this;
        vm.delete=function(){
          alert('--');
          sharedService.deletepro();
        }

      }).directive('b',function(){

     return {
    restrict :'E',
    scope:{},
    templateUrl:'b.html',
    controller:'bb',
    controllerAs:'vm'
  }

      }).controller('bb',function(sharedService){
        var pm=this;
        pm.message= sharedService.sendData();

      }).service('sharedService',function(){
         var vm =this
         vm.data={};
         vm.sendData=sendData;
         vm.deletepro=deletepro;
         function deletepro(){
            vm.data={};
         }
         function sendData(){
           var obj ={name:"pQr"};
           vm.data=obj;
           return vm.data;
         }

      })
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

I try to delete like that but not work

```
vm.delete=function(){
          alert('--');
          sharedService.deletepro();
        }
```

Update answer provide not working

updated plinker

http://plnkr.co/edit/Yenmira9J9XpjscQzRoX?p=preview

Comment: `delete myObject.property` deletes the property named `property` from the object referred to by `myObject`, but it looks like your problem is probably a callback that isn't firing.  Have you tried putting log statements in each callback to see what is firing and in what order.

Comment: sorry I am using angular js ..please first take a look on plunker

Comment: negative voters pls try to answer this Question ..it is good question and i tried a lot then after i asked this

Comment: I don't understand all the down votes either. The mistake you are making is a legitimate one; the difference between Angular service and factory recipes is not obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the .service recipe, which creates a constructor, but what you want to use is the .factory recipe, which creates a singleton.

```
.factory('sharedService', function() {
    var data = {};

    function deletepro(){
        data = {};
    }

    function sendData(){
        var obj = {name:"pQr"};
        data = obj;
        return data;
    }

    return {
        sendData: sendData,
        deletepro: deletepro
    };
});
```

This way, both of your controllers will load the same instance of your shared service.

**UPDATE**

After reviewing your code on the plnkr provided in your comment, I found a few more errors in your code.

- You had a typo in one of your controllers, as mentioned in another answer (`pm` instead of `vm`)
- You were assigning the return value of `sharedService.sendData()` to `vm.message`, but that did not bind the two values in any way.

In the second case, you were expecting the value of `vm.message` to update when you made a change to the data in `sharedService`, but because there was no binding, that was not happening.

To resolve it, I added a link function to your directive and used the following code to watch `sharedService.getData` and update `vm.message` whenever it changed:

```
scope.$watch(sharedService.getData, function(data) {
    vm.message = data;
}
```

Here is a working version: http://plnkr.co/edit/kd7aEgNdQnTuMlwcTeDE?p=preview

Comment: please remove your answer so that other will answer

Comment: See my updated answer. I hope this answers your question.

Comment: could you please answer of this Question also..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34431114/how-to-empty-reference-object-in-angular-js?noredirect=1#comment56604279_34431114

Comment: Can't get to it tonight, but I will try and take a look tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

First: You have a mistake in the second directive, you declare `controllerAs: 'vm'` but in the controller you have a distinct scope variable name: `var pm = this;`

To delete a property you cant try:

```
delete myObject[property];
```

where property is a string.

**Happy coding!**